# file:inbound-channel-adapter prevent-duplicates="false" is not working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

My application is a Spring Boot application. I have a directory named `abc`. I have created an inbound adapter to read the directory for new files. Let's assume a file `aa.txt` present in the directory. It is being picked up by the adapter. Now, let's say, again a new file with the same name has been saved in the directory. But, now the adapter does not get invoked.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter"
    directory="file:abc" filter="txtFiles"
    auto-startup="true" prevent-duplicates="false">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I have set `prevent-duplicates=false`. Still, that file is not getting picked up. Why does this happen? What is the solution?

Comment: is another file like `ab.txt` invoked after `aa.txt` is invoked?

Comment: if another file "ab.txt" comes, it is invoked.

Comment: You can turn on the debug logging for Spring integration - that may give you and idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. I have set prevent-duplicates=false to the filter bean(FileListFilterFactoryBean), instead of inbound-channel-adapter & it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The default `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` does not look at the lastModified file attribute, just the file name.

The `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` compares the timestamp so will pass a modified file with the same name.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html).

> The `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` stores its state in memory. If you wish the state to survive a system restart, consider using the `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` instead. This filter stores the accepted file names in a MetadataStore implementation (Section 9.5, “Metadata Store”). This filter matches on the filename and modified time.

Comment: Can you share some information or link which shows how to use FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter ?